# how to implement join to more than one table on same column in doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query

My scenario is like this.

item_master table

```
item_id (primary key) | item_name
--------------------------------------
      1               |     Keyboard
--------------------------------------
      2               |     Mouse
--------------------------------------
```

user_lp_requirement table

```
id1 |item_id | otherColumns1
-----------------------
1   |  1     | 1
-----------------------
1   |  2     | 3
-----------------------
item_id is foreign key reference to item_master
```

training_program table

```
id2 |item_id | otherColumns2
-----------------------
1   |  1     | 1
-----------------------
1   |  2     | 4
-----------------------
item_id is foreign key reference to item_master
```

edit:
In entity I have user_lp_requirement.item_id mapped to item_master.item_id. So if i mention item_id in query builder join, it automatically joins user_lp_requirement to item_master

Now the problem is how to join user_lp_requirement to training_program on "item_id" using doctrine queryBuilder.

FYI->the query will be written in Application\Entity\Repository\UserLpRequirementRepository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$queryBuilder
    ->select('u', 'i.item_name', 't.otherColumns2')
    ->from('user_lp_requirement', 'u')
    ->innerJoin('u', 'item_master', 'i', 'u.item_id = i.item_id')
    ->innerJoin('u', 'training_program', 't', 'u.item_id = t.item_id');
```

This assumes that you want the user table mapped to the item table AND the user table mapped to the training table rather than the user table mapped to a join of the training table and the item table.

Comment: it gives error: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 42 near 'user_lp_requirements': Error: Class 'user_lp_requirements' is not defined.

Comment: You might check your entity definitions.  The class you refer to in your question is `user_lp_requirement` (no s).  The class referred to in the error message is `user_lp_requirements` (with an s).  Also, it's good practice to identify edits you make to your question after an answer is posted so that other readers can follow the dialog.

Comment: i got the answer:

$queryBuilder
    ->select(array('ulr', 'im.item_name', 'tp.otherColumns2'))
    ->from('Application\Entity\UserLpRequirements', 'ulr')
    ->innerJoin('ulr.item', 'im')
    ->innerJoin('Application\Entity\TrainingProgram', 'tp', JOIN::WITH, 'tp.item=ulr.itemId');

your answer helped a lot to find my answer.